# C# - how to check if string value has changed within a different class?

Tags: c#, string, class

I have a class as follows:

```
class TestSomeData
{
    public string someString;
    public void CheckSomeStuff()
    {
         foreach(string x in someList)
         {
              someString = x;
          }
     }
 }
```

What i want to do is this:

```
TestSomeData test = new TestSomeData;
test.CheckSomeStuff();
label1.Content = test.someString;
```

So if x is 1,2,3,4,5 out of someList in CheckSomeStuff, i need the label1.Content to reflect that, but from a different class.  how do i do that?

Comment: You want the other class to know if the value of `someString` changes?

Comment: do you need label1.Content to always reflect the current state of someString, or do you need to set it once and be done with?

Comment: Also, note that the foreach loop is unnecessary as someString always end up with the last value in someList.

Comment: Are you using winforms or WPF? Or something else. How about using binding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class can inform other classes of changes made to it by declaring events

```
public class SomeDataClass
{
    public event EventHandler SomeDataChanged;

    private string _someData;
    public string SomeData
    {
        get { return _someData; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _someData) {
                _someData = value;
                OnSomeDataChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnSomeDataChanged()
    {
        SomeDataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class InterestedClass
{
    public void Work()
    {
        var someData = new SomeDataClass();
        someData.SomeDataChanged += someData_SomeDataChanged;
        someData.SomeData = "New Value";
    }

    void someData_SomeDataChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some data changed: {0}", ((SomeDataClass)sender).SomeData);
    }
}
```

You could also make the event static. This would allow a listener to listen to changes of any instance of this class.

```
SomeDataClass.SomeDataChanged += SomeDataClass_SomeDataChanged;

var someData = new SomeDataClass();
someData.SomeData = "New Value";
var someOtherData = new SomeDataClass();
someData.SomeData = "Other Value";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a reference to the control so that you can change its text directly. Not saying this design is particularly *pretty* but it would get the job done.

```
class TestSomeData
{
    public TestSomeData(Label myControl) {
        this.MyControl = myControl;
    }

    private Label MyControl { get; set; }

    public void CheckSomeStuff()
    {
         if (this.MyControl == null) {
             // throw ArgumentNullException or InvalidOperationException
         }

         foreach(string x in someList)
         {
              this.MyControl.Content = x;
         }
     }
 }
```

Also as others have noted, the control will always have the **last** value found in the list. If you're trying to have the label display each value as the list enumerates you're going to have to add some UI logic to force the control to refresh or repaint.

Comment: might be good to check it for null before setting it's content?

Comment: @codesparkle Sure. I'll edit for that. For brevity I just wanted to make the minimal changes to accomplish the task.

Comment: This makes the class more tightly coupled with a label control. What if he needs to use it later with something else? Event handlers are really the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should make that field [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx). All instances of that class will have that something in common. Any change will be globally.

Comment: I don't think thats got anything to do with the question.

Comment: from what he says he wants to access that value from another class

Comment: making it static will not change anything in respect to accessibility from another class.

Comment: check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx, I think he doesn't know what he wants in this matter, but i think this will help